# Django exclude Items from Queryset from another Queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a quite complicated model setup:

- Audiofiles are stored in different databases.
- Users can select a database and then a random audiofile should be
  selected.
- For each database a list of questions is available and one will be
  randomly picked as well.
- The answers are saved and each time the user accesses a database I
  have to make sure that he does not get the same combination of
  (Audiofile, Question) which he has already answered.

Here my code:

```
class Database(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    questions = models.ManyToManyField(Question)

class AudioData(models.Model):    
    database = models.ForeignKey(Database)

class Question(models.Model):
    ...

# added as a helper class for this problem
class AudioQuestionPair(models.Model):
    audioData = models.ForeignKey(AudioData)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    database = models.ForeignKey(Database)

class NewAnswer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    audioData = models.ForeignKey(AudioData)
    timestamp = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    body = models.TextField()
```

I'm trying to figure out, how to (efficiently and without running into an infinite loop) select an available Audio, Question pair. Currently I got to the point that I can get a dict of answers, containing only the required IDs and a list of pairs. But I can't figure out how to exclude answers from pairs.

```
answers = NewAnswer.objects.filter(user=request.user).filter(audioData__database=id).values('audioData_id', 'question_id')
```

Results in

```
[{'audioData_id': 2, 'question_id': 2}, {'audioData_id': 1, 'question_id': 1}]
```

And to get all available pairs

```
pairs = AudioQuestionPair.objects.filter(database=id).values('audioData_id', 'question_id')
```

Results in

```
 [{'audioData_id': 1, 'question_id': 1}, {'audioData_id': 2, 'question_id': 1}, {'audioData_id': 5, 'question_id': 1}, {'audioData_id': 6, 'question_id': 1}, {'audioData_id': 7, 'question_id': 1}]
```

How can I exclude this in a third step now?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

edit: sorry for not understanding your issue right away;

it seems that the dirtiest option is cycling over each answer:

```
answers = NewAnswer.objects.filter(user=request.user).filter(audioData__database=id).values_list('audioData_id', 'question_id')
available_pairs = AudioQuestionPair.objects.filter(database=id)
for a in answers:
    available_pairs = available_pairs.exclude(audioData_id=a[0], question_id=a[1])
```

It should also be possible to cycle over every `NewAnswer` and build a (possibly huge) `Q` object and use it to execute a big OR query, but I'm not sure if this will improve the performance a lot, considering that `QuerySet`s are not evaluated until being looked at.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. It need to stay as pairs. Imagine having 3 Audiofiles (IDs 1,2,3) and 3 Questions (IDs 1,2,3), that would create 9 possible solutions: (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1) and so on. With two exclude statements chained together, it will remove (1,x) if AudioFile with ID 1 has at least one question answered

Comment: You are definitely right; I edited my answer to a different approach.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm on the right track. Still not working though. answered_audios and answered_questions are the same, apparently you have to filter it immediately, in first line add this to the chain: .values_list('audiodata_id', 'question_id'). Output is[(2, 2), (1, 1)]. Now I have a list of tuples, which I splitted into two lists: lists1, list2 = zip(*answers). Output is: (2, 1) and (2, 1), but when using Q it will not only remove (2,2) and (1,1) but also (2,1) and (1,2) now. AudioQuestionPair.objects.filter(database=id).exclude(Q(audioData_id__in=list1) & Q(question_id__in=list2))

Comment: Edited again; hope this will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, using the loop it's working. However, for each iteration when available_pairs.exclude is executed, will there be a new connection / query to the database or will it only happen in memory?

Comment: As per [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy), the database should not be hit at all in the code I provided; it will build a query that will be executed when (and if) you will use the contents of the variable `available_pairs`.